# How can I develop trial version of software

Tags: c#, .net, time-trial

I mean that my software must be run for only 7 days when it is installed on any system.
It is possible with registry but i dont know how it is possible.

Comment: there are commercial frameworks for this... Failing that on startup check the date! (easily defeated of course)

Answer (score 3):

Pseudo-code:

```
if myRegistryKey exists:
    dayOfFirstRun = read(myRegistryKey)
    if today > dayOfFirstRun + 7 days:
        -- Trial Version Expired --
    else
        -- ((dayOfFirstRun + 7 days) - today) Days Left --
else
    write(myRegistryKey, today)
```

That should be enough to get you started. Obviously, this simple method can be circumvented quite easily. For more advanced algorithms, have a look at the following related questions (and countless others on StackOverflow):

- [Need Advice on Implementing a Time-limited Trial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197999/87698)
- [How to create trial version of .NET software?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2423976/87698)